# Why does PHP not allow the use of a decimal value as a root key in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, superglobals

Why does PHP not allow the use of a decimal value as a root key in $_SESSION?

For example...

```
$paper_num = '159339';
$mark = 'A';

$_SESSION[$paper_num][$mark];
```

... Doesn't work.

Comment: Better try and see the out come

Comment: It doesn't work with '159339' but it does work if I replace the root key with 'A' for example. I was hoping for a good explanation as to the logic behind this... Seems weird but I'm sure there is a good reason.

Comment: Ive updated the question to try and get some more in depth answers.

Comment: I think php will convert `'159339'` to just `159339`(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant you save it in the session as an array eg..

```
<?php
session_start();
$paper_num = '159339';
$mark = 'A';

$paper_detail = array(
'paper_number'=> $paper_num,
'paper_mark'=> $mark);

$_SESSION['paper_details'] = $paper_detail;
print_r($_SESSION['paper_details']);
?>
```

Comment: no problem, then you can access each variable like `$_SESSION['paper_details']['paper_number']` or `$_SESSION['paper_details']['paper_mark']`